# what .js and .css files to include when setting up jstree

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, jstree

I have downloaded the files from [jstree home](http://www.jstree.com/) downoad link. i am already using jquery library.

The download contains the following files
1. _lib (three .js files)
2. themes (different theme styles(.css), also includes pics for jstree)
3. _docs folder(documentation notes)
4. _demo(demonstation files)
5. jquery.jstree.js(currently i have only included this file in my app)

What files(pics .js & .css) do i need to include in my rails app from the download. I have seen links to other _libs that you can download.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only wanted the base jsTree install you would include:

```
jquery.jstree.js
themes/default/style.css
themes/default/ (Copy this entire folder into your project)
```

Then you can include:

```
jquery.cookie.js - For cookie support
jquery.hotkeys.js - For keyboard support
```

Comment: @BladeOrz thanks i just realized that i had another file style.css, that was causing conflict, thanks anyway.